# 'keyPress()' method for Robot object isn't typing anything

Tags: java, keypress, awtrobot

I'm trying to code a program in Java that automatically types each character in a string using the Robot class. I've used it to make a similar automated program a while ago (which I'll refer to as the 'previous project') that used 'keyPress()'. This and most, if not all, of the other methods for the Robot class which I needed to use worked perfectly.

Now I've started and 'keyPress()' isn't typing anything, regardless of the KeyEvent I pass as an argument. I thought I had written the code incorrectly, so I ran my previous project just to make sure it worked, but it didn't.

Here's the snippet of code I used for the previous project and my current one (which you can also use to test this).

EDIT: Try the on a text editor or anything that functions like a text field. I've now shown the entire demo class.

```
// demo procedure
public class DemoClass() {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DemoClass().run()
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            
            for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
                robot.delay(100);

                System.out.println("Typed key");
            }

        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

'Typed key' gets printed 30 times and no errors appear in the output either.

I've tried;

- adding 'robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A)' just after the key press,
- allowing the program type in the software I want to automate,
- allowing the program to type in the IDE I'm using and in a text editor,
- allowing the program to click in the IDE and text editor (so I could see if only pressing keys was the issue).

None of these have produced results. I've checked the code from multiple sources (articles and videos), all of which have the same code stub. I've read that some software prevent Robot objects from typing/clicking in them, but both typing and clicking worked when I was developing my previous project.

Comment: Key events are only passed to the component with focus. We have no context on how that code is actually used. Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. *but both typing and clicking worked when I was developing my previous project.* - then go back to your previous project to see what you did differently.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I had whatever I wanted to type into in focus (which I'll add to the post). Like I said, this is the same code snippet used in my previous project that used to work before but doesn't now. I've changed nothing in the project since then either.

Comment: @GreatPanda3 I just tried your code it worked perfect

Comment: @UmerFarooq Really? Did you copy the code exactly? Did you let the program write in a particular kind of text field or just a standard text editor? I'm not sure why it isn't working for me if you did all of the above.

Comment: @GreatPanda3 Yes i copied the exact code you provided. I let the program to type in IDE and in Notepad and it worked (typed sequences of 'a')

Comment: @UmerFarooq That's weird... thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @GreatPanda3 Try running your IDE as an administrator

Comment: @UmerFarooq Thanks for the help. I did some research and tried executing the 'sudo' command in the terminal to open my IDE as a root (I'm on a mac and I'm not too advanced in using the terminal... it looked like root was the same thing as making it an administrator). Unfortunately it didn't work. Maybe I did the wrong thing?

Answer (score 1):

So I woke up today and... the program works.

I still don't know why it wasn't working in the first place or how the problem fixed itself (magic?). Running the sudo command didn't seem to make a difference, and none of the software I'm dealing with prevent a Robot object from automated typing/clicking.

It's most likely just a me-problem since other people managed to get it working. Since it's happened once it'll probably happen again.

Anyways, thanks to everyone that helped! If future readers have any ideas of why it didn't work then feel free to share them.